# Comparing morphisms of algebraic structures and topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, category-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be groups, it seems natural to me that a proper function (homomorphism) $\phi$  from $X$ to $Y$ has this property that $\phi \subset X \times Y$ is a subgroup. Is there a way to define continuous functions similarly?

Comment: Are you suggesting that there is a relation between group homomorphisms and proper maps in topology?

Comment: @AlexProvost no I didn't use "proper" as a mathematical term.

Comment: Any subset of a topological set is a subspace via the subspace topology. Unlike with groups where you need _specific_ subsets.

Comment: I haven't worked through this to check it but intuitively it seems that in the topological case the graph of a continuous map ought to be connected (at least if the domain $X$ is connected) as a subspace of the product space $X\times Y$. I'm not sure about the logical necessity/sufficiency of this condition though.

Comment: @alex, if X is connected, it is connected because it is the image of X under a continuous function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you restrict to compact Hausdorff spaces, this works out very nicely.  First, note that if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, a "sub-compact Hausdorff space" of $X$ is a closed subspace of $X$ (closed since it needs to be compact; note also that these correspond to monomorphisms in the sense of category theory).  Then the following is true: a function $\phi:X\to Y$ between compact Hausdorff spaces is continuous iff its graph $\Gamma\subseteq X\times Y$ is closed (i.e., iff its graph is a sub-compact Hausdorff space).

To prove this, first suppose $\phi$ is continuous.  Then $\Gamma$ is the image of a continuous map $X\to X\times Y$ (namely, $x\mapsto(x,\phi(x))$), and so is compact since $X$ is compact, and hence is closed since $X\times Y$ is Hausdorff.  Conversely, if $\Gamma$ is closed, then it is compact, so the projection $\Gamma\to X$ must be a homeomorphism, since it is a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space.  Since $\phi$ is the composition of the inverse of this bijection with the projection $\Gamma\to Y$, it follows that $\phi$ is continuous.

Note that this breaks down for general spaces.  For instance, if $X=Y$ is not Hausdorff, then the identity map $X\to X$ is continuous, but its graph is not closed (the diagonal in $X\times X$ is closed iff $X$ is Hausdorff).  And if $Y$ is discrete and $X$ is $T_1$, then any injection $X\to Y$ has closed graph, but such an injection is not continuous unless $X$ is also discrete.  In general, as Captain Lama's answer discusses, you need to directly require that the projection $\Gamma\to X$ is a homeomorphism, which cannot be translated into saying $\Gamma$ is some special kind of subspace of $X\times Y$ without reference to the projection maps.

Much more generally, if you have any monad $T$ on the category of sets and $X$ and $Y$ are $T$-algebras, a function $\phi:X\to Y$ between the underlying sets is a homomorphism iff its graph is a subalgebra of $X\times Y$ (the proof is straightforward once you write down what all the words actually mean).  It is a nontrivial theorem that the category of compact Hausdorff spaces can be considered as the algebras over a monad on sets, and the characterization of continuity for compact Hausdorff spaces given above follows.

For some related discussion, you may be interested in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/179200/75) of mine on MathOverflow, which explores these ideas in the context of defining what it would mean for a multivalued function (i.e., a relation) to be continuous.

Comment: Woah, the fact that compact spaces form a monad over sets is really neat, I had never seen that anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

The thing is, you can't take *any* subgroup $G\subset X\times Y$. It has to satisfy that the first projection gives an isomorphism $G\to X$. In the category of groups, being an isomorphism is the same as being bijective, so you can sort of define morphisms that way just knowing about functions.

But for topological spaces, the graph of a continuous function $X\to Y$ has to satisfy that the first projection is a *homeomorphism*. So if you want to define continuous functions that way, you have to know about products, subspaces *and* homeomorphisms.

But yes, if you know about these, you can define a continuous function as a subspace of the product such that the fist projection induces a homeomorphism, since then from $\Gamma_f\subset X\times Y$ you have $f(x) = \pi_2(\pi_1^{-1}(x))$ continuous where $\pi_i$ are the two projections $X\times Y\to X,Y$, and $\pi_1^{-1}:X\to \Gamma_f$ is the inverse of $\pi_1:\Gamma_f\to X$.

Comment: For $\phi $ to be a homomorphism ,it just needs to be a function(left-total relation) and  be a subgroup of $X \times Y$. I think demanding that the first projection be isomorphism is redundant. not?

Comment: Example : the trivial subgroup of $X\times Y$. It is not the graph of any function $X\to Y$, since such a graph must contain an element $(x,y)$ for all $x\in X$. So you really need the first projection to be bijective : it just expresses that any element has one and one only image. In the case of groups, bijectivity is the same as being an isomorphism (since the projection is always a morphism), so you don't have to worry too much about it, but this is no longer the case for topological spaces.

Comment: @CaptainLama: I think that Kavim means that a function $f$ from a group $X$ to a group $Y$ is a homomorphism if and only if it is a subgroup of $X \times Y$. In fact one can define a morphism as a function of which the graph is a subgroup of the product. So one can completely avoid talking about projections in the group case.

Comment: Ah yes sure, I didn't understand that. Indeed. This will be the case for all concrete categories whose forgetful functor to Set reflects isomorphisms.