# Which subsets of products are graphs of continuous maps?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map between topological spaces, and let $\Gamma_f\subseteq X\times Y$ be its graph $\{(x,f(x))\mid x\in X\}$. Is there a (general) predicate $P(S',S)$ on pairs with $S'$ arbitrary subset of a topological space $S$ such that $f$ is continuous if and only $P(\Gamma_f,X\times Y)$ holds?

(When $Y$ is compact Hausdorff, the [closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem) says the answer is just "$S'$ is a closed subset of $S$").

Comment: You may also be interested in both of the answers at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695903/comparing-morphisms-of-algebraic-structures-and-topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not, at least assuming you want the predicate to be homeomorphism-invariant.  If such a predicate existed, then note that by swapping the coordinates on $X\times Y$, you would get that a bijection $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff the inverse $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ is continous.  But this is not true in general.